# Navigate through different Android xml activities

Tags: android

I am new to android development and am using android studio in ubuntu to write a simple Android app.

Right now the main activity `activity_go` is an xml file which describes the first set of objects being displayed.  By adding a click listener to a button object described on `activities_go.xml`

I am able to change the activity to another set of objects, 'two' which corresponds with `two.xml`

The Following is the java code I am currently using to switch between xml files

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_go);
    Button nxtButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    nxtButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            setContentView(R.layout.two);
        }
    });
}
```

Upon running this I am able to display `two.xml` once the button is clicked.

How Can I do this again, upon clicking a button on `two.xml` change to `three.xml` ?

or is there a better method to shift between the layout xml for android applications?

Comment: I don't know what is your goal, but you can try with [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you need to view [trainings](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) by Google. [This article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) is about your case.